# What does 'listen to the shorter body scans or longer visualizations' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was looking at a service that revolves around curing anxiety and panic attacks and I saw this:

> Listen to the shorter body scans or longer visualizations below to get
>   rooted when you are feeling anxious.

This text is about a body scan/meditation feature of the service.

It seems body scan meditation is a sort of guided meditation that helps one develop mindful awareness of bodily sensations. Besides, there is another type of meditation called 'visualization meditation', when the focus of a meditation is an image, the meditation becomes visualization. Therefore, there are two kinds of meditations in this context.

However, I still can't understand what exactly 'listen to shorter body scans or longer visualizations' means, especially because I don't know what's below this paragraph.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: It does not make sense to me. "Listen" implies "to a sound", but a scan, and certainly a visualization, is something that one *sees*. Could it be that the text is a poor translation from another langauge?

Comment: It seems body scan meditation is a sort of guided meditation that helps one develop mindful awareness of bodily sensations. When the focus of a meditation is an image, the meditation becomes visualization.

P.S It's not a translation from another language. I actually have to translate this text into another language but it doesn't seem to be written in an understandable way.

Comment: You ask what "shorter body scans" or "longer visualizations" means in context, but you haven't written what is *below* (the context). As written, this reads like a health sciences question and not an English language one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with a vocabulary peculiar to a site, not English vocabulary in general use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that "below" the paragraph are several things that you could listen to. The shorter ones are "body scans" and the longer ones are "visualisations".  These words would appear to be used by the website to meaning something particular relating to the service; they don't have their usual meaning.  The normal meaning of "body scan" is like the metal detector you walk through at the airport. A "visualisation" is a act of making something visual. In the normal meaning these can't be listened to.

Apparently listening to these "body scans" or "visualisations" will enable you to "get rooted", which apparently means to regain control of your feelings.